# How to fix "Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to make a simple calculator and am stuck after trying to using the getAttribute method to retrieve my custom data-* attribute.

I made sure the var used to store the elements does indeed house them

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-orange" data-num="*">*</button>
```

```
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        var number = btns[i].getAttribute("data-num");
        screen.value += number;
    });
}
```

There are 15 buttons in total with class="btn". I have checked in the console and btns does indeed hold 15 elements. I don't understand why `getAttribute("data-num")` is returning undefined when I click any of the buttons with the stated class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: on which iteration does it fail in the loop?

Comment: @JuanDM, you may be misunderstanding how `<` and `[].length` works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this` inside function definition instead of `btns[i]` as below:

```
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        var number = this.getAttribute("data-num");
        screen.value += number;
    });
}
```

Basically you have created `click` event function for each button and you are using `i` inside these function. When this function executes, it checks `i` value which will be the last value of loop, (if you have 6 `.btn` class then `i` will have 6) because you are not binding `i` current value with function. So on each click, you will get last value which will break code.

To avoid this, you can either use above code or can bind variables in function as below:

```
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(iBindededValue){
        var number = btns[iBindededValue].getAttribute("data-num");
        screen.value += number;
    }.bind(this, i));
}
```

Here we can bind `i` with current value with each function and can use that. You can refer bind function to check its functionality. Hope it helps you to understand its flow, Cheers!!

Comment: This solves the problem elegantly, but doesn't explain WHY `btns[i]` doesn't work.

Comment: Provided the clarification @junvar

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `i` is mutated but you're using it INSIDE the event listener. If you log `i` when adding the event listeners, you'll get `0, 1, 2, 3`, as expected. However, if you log `i` **inside the event listener, `i` is ALWAYS be `4`**, and so `btns[i]` is undefined.

Simply keep a separate reference of `i`, or better yet of `btns[i]` as below:

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
    btn = btns[i];
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(i, btns[i]); // i == 4, btns[i] == undefined !!!!
        var number = btn.getAttribute("data-num");
        console.log(number);
    });
}
```

```html
<button class='btn' data-num='0'>0</button>
<button class='btn' data-num='1'>1</button>
<button class='btn' data-num='2'>2</button>
<button class='btn' data-num='3'>3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came to this page with exactly the same problem !! After trying the suggestions and getting the same error, I re-checked the data-items I was using. Because I was working on a diary project, mine had dates:

```
    <pre>
        <li data-date="#01/01/1900">The Past</li>
        <li data-date="#01/04/1994">Apr '94</li>
        <li data-date="#01/10/1996" class="selected">Oct '96</li>
        <li data-date="#01/09/2005">Sep '05</li>
    </pre>
```

These were designed to align with a second list containing further information:

```
    <pre>
        <li id="01/01/1900">
        <li id="01/04/1994">
        <li id="01/10/1996" class="selected">
        <li id="01/09/2005">
    </pre>
```

I knew that I had the correct selectors and eventListener, as I had used similar code previously:

```
    <pre>
            const events = document.querySelectorAll(".events ol li");

            events.forEach((event) => {
                event.addEventListener("click", () => {
  
                    const eventDate = this.getAttribute("data-date");
                    const eventInfo = document.querySelector(eventDate);

                    console.log(eventDate);
                    console.log(eventInfo);
                });
            });
    </pre>
```

But the error persisted !!

It was only when I tried changing the data-date and ID items to simply "first", "second", "third", "fourth" etc that the errors disappeared, and my code worked as expected.

In conclusion: remove any punctuation from your IDs and data-items.